Scala Matchers for compare Options with Array
By using org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
I'm trying to compare values with type Option[Array[String]]
But method  "Matchers.should equals" returns false, when I compare
val arr1 = Some(Array("1","2"))

with
val arr2 = Some(Array("1","2"))

So
 arr1 should arr2

returns :
 Some(Array("1", "2")) was not equal to Some(Array("1", "2"))
 Some(value: [Ljava.lang.String;@14a2026c -> [Ljava.lang.String;@6e965714)

What am I doing wrong?

This question is similar to: How do I compare two arrays in scala?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is not the Option. Also scalatest provides the trait OptionValues to do assertion over options and get better error messages in case the test fails. The equals method in arrays is not the correct one to compare them

Don't use Arrays unless you very much know what toy are doing.

Array is a mutable data structure which is compared by identity, i.e. the following code runs to completion without any issue:
val a = Array(1, 2)
val b = Array(1, 2)
val c = a

assert(a != b)
assert(a == c)

Array is a data structure historically inherited from the JVM and its definition of equality contrasts that of the collections defined by the Scala Collection API (for which a simple shouldEqual would suffice).
To enable you comparing "containers" regardless of their identity, you can use its special support for it.
To give you a practical example of it, the following test will pass:
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

final class MySpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {

  "test" should "pass" in {
    Array("1", "2") should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs Array("1", "2")
  }

}

To move one step further and also go into composing this with the ability of inspecting an Option, you can use OptionValues (docs). Again, here is the revised test that should do what you expect to:
  "other test" should "pass too" in {
    val a = Some(Array("1", "2"))
    val b = Some(Array("1", "2"))
    a.value should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs b.value
  }

You can play around with the code above here on Scastie.
